# Increment non-adjacent cell's reference by 1 in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, reference, increment, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet with this:

[image: Sheet6]

I'm trying to collect these names in a different Sheet so it can load an API but that API loads 10 lines so between each name I need a 10 line space, leaving it like this:

[image: Api]

Right now if I copy and paste `A1` (Which formula is: `Sheet6!A2`) in `A21` it will appear as `Sheet6!A22` instead of `Sheet6!A4`.

I've done this manually but I have hundreds of these so I'd like a way to get these cell references just by dragging, copy-paste or any other faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY({
 "♦"&INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))&"♠Sheet6!A"&
 ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)))&"♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦"},,999^99), "♦")), "♠"))
```

[image: 0]

---

if you just want to add 9 empty rows between names do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY({
 "♦"&INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))&"♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦ ♦"},,999^99), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

---

or like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT("♦"&TEXTJOIN(REPT("♠♦", 10), 1, A2:A), "♦"), "♠", )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It's insane how that worked, I was definitely asking the second one but I'm amazed how fast you did that. As a newbie I have no clue what these symbols mean but it does the job. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TraaZ symbols means nothing. it's just for `SPLIT` formula to be able to cut the string exactly where needed. also added one more solution...

Comment: That last one also works perfectly, only thing I'd say is it can't have anything below that formula cause it would overwrite it but I just moved the api query to the right so it's not important.